# How to make a grouping of all API call

Tags: reactjs, rest

Goal:
Create a api.js for grouping all api call into a single file.

Problem:
If you have many webpages with many api calls, how should you create a group of all api call into a single file?
Do you have a sample?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pvb5w2

Info:
*Angular has a grouping of all call by using service but I don't know if it possibly to create the same approach for react js. Do you have a sample?
*I'm newbie in reactjs.

Thank you!

Comment: add a sample code please

Comment: what your code is should likes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pvb5w2

Comment: You can try using Redux and then group your API calls inside actions files. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Why using redux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky to solve it.

By support and reflection from this website below I was enable to find a solution to my problem.
You need to group api into a single api.js and also to make the url adress to promote DRY by using api-config.js.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/svelte-imozn2
https://daveceddia.com/multiple-environments-with-react/

The answer is located at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3tj4gv